# MockitoAnnotationns openMocks AutoClosable

Tags: mockito

I'm trying to understand the purpose of the MockitoAnnotations openMocks method returning an AutoClosable. The docs mention it should be called if static mocks are used, but I haven't found any examples actually showing the usage of static mocks + calling the close method together. The examples I've seen online don't seem to have any consistency around if/when the close method is even called on the returned AutoClosable.

Can anyone help offer a better explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I also have trouble understanding whether or not one should close the `AutoClosable` returned from `MockitoAnnotations.openMocks()` so I looked at the Docs.

The [JavaDoc from the MockitoAnnotations](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/5.8.0/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html) class closes it in the example, so for me that is a strong hint to close the AutoCloseable.

I also found the [MockitoSession](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/5.8.0/org/mockito/MockitoSession.html), which is supposed to be used when you cannot use the  MockitoJUnitRunner or MockitoRule. The Mockito Session automatically closes the alle the `AutoCloseable`s, see the [source code](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/main/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/framework/DefaultMockitoSession.java#L100).

So I feel like the default usage of Mockito is to use the MockitoJUnitRunner (or rather the JUnit 5 equivalent [MockitoExtension](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/latest/org/mockito/junit/jupiter/MockitoExtension.html)) which apparently uses the MockitoSession (so closes the AutoClosable). If you cannot use those, you should either use MockitoSession or manually open and close the mocks.

But I still think that the JavaDoc of the method openMocks should be more specific about whether or not you should close. Unfortunately, you can easily find examples which do not close the AutoCloseable.